# pcie USB add on card recognized by Elementary OS but not Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb

I have USB 3.0 card (Vantec UGT-PC345) recognized by Elementary OS an Ubuntu derivative, however, it is not recognized by Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.
Here is `uname -a`

```
Linux 4.8.0-51-generic #54~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 16:00:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and here is `lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DMI2 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D DMI2
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
    Capabilities: [144] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0004 Rev=1 Len=03c <?>
    Capabilities: [1d0] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0003 Rev=1 Len=00a <?>
    Capabilities: [280] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0005 Rev=3 Len=018 <?>
    Capabilities: [300] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0008 Rev=0 Len=038 <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 1
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
    Capabilities: [110] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [148] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [1d0] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0003 Rev=1 Len=00a <?>
    Capabilities: [250] #19
    Capabilities: [280] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0005 Rev=3 Len=018 <?>
    Capabilities: [300] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0008 Rev=0 Len=038 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: fb300000-fb3fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
    Capabilities: [110] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [148] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [1d0] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0003 Rev=1 Len=00a <?>
    Capabilities: [250] #19
    Capabilities: [280] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0005 Rev=3 Len=018 <?>
    Capabilities: [300] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0008 Rev=0 Len=038 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: fa000000-fb0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D PCI Express Root Port 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=0 Len=00c <?>
    Capabilities: [110] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [148] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [1d0] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0003 Rev=1 Len=00a <?>
    Capabilities: [250] #19
    Capabilities: [280] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0005 Rev=3 Len=018 <?>
    Capabilities: [300] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0008 Rev=0 Len=038 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Map/VTd_Misc/System Management (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Map/VTd_Misc/System Management
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00

00:05.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO Hot Plug (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO Hot Plug
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0006 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [110] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0006 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [120] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0006 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [130] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0006 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>

00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO RAS/Control Status/Global Errors (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D IIO RAS/Control Status/Global Errors
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00

00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D I/O APIC (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [IO(X)-APIC])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D I/O APIC
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at fb43e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [e0] Power Management version 3

00:11.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SPSR (rev 05)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset SPSR
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:11.4 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset sSATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset sSATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at f130 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f120 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f110 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f100 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Memory at fb43d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset USB xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at fb420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
    Memory at fb43c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at fb400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at fb439000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at fb438000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 62
    Memory at fb430000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: fb200000-fb2fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: fb100000-fb1fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at fb437000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset 6-Port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset 6-Port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f070 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Memory at fb436000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. C610/X99 series chipset SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 4
    Memory at fb435000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
    I/O ports at 0580 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti]
    Physical Slot: 4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fb0 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 4998
    Physical Slot: 4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 63
    Memory at fb080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Physical Slot: 6
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at fb300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fb200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=32]
    Memory at fb280000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=5 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-1f-bc-ff-ff-11-b8-f9
    Capabilities: [1a0] Transaction Processing Hints
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb

06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fb110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fb100000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [168] #19
    Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:8110 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c331 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2109:2811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1b1c:0c0a Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:8110 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 046d:c332 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:2811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is there a kernel difference between the two different distros or do I need to install some driver?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue with a cold boot. I shut down the machine, turned off the power supply and held the power button until the internal indicator lights on the motherboard turned off. I then booted the system and several new hardware devices were detected! It also fixed some networking issues that I had.